# php echod JavaScript won't run?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a problem where when I echo JavaScript from a PHP page to a HTML page using AJAX it won't run however, when I Inspect Element the JavaScript is there, I also echo some text and the text does show.

When I add the JavaScript manually in the HTML it works perfectly and the PHP, HTML and AJAX files are all in the same directory so there is no problem there.

I have 3 pages  index.html, boo.php and ajax.js

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.gritter.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load('jquery', '1.7.1');</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gritter.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
refreshdiv();
// --></script>

<div id="timediv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**boo.php**

```
<?php

// Fetch the data

$query = "SELECT * FROM $tablename";
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Return the results, loop through them and echo

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

$name = $row['name']; // this equals Admin

if($name == 'Admin') {

echo $name; // this echos Admin and shows on index.html


// the javascript below doesnt
 echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function(){



        $(document).ready( function () {

            var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
                title: 'title text',
                text: 'description text',

                image: 'icon.jpg',

                sticky: true,

                time: '',

                class_name: 'my-sticky-class'
            });



            return false;

        });


    });
</script>
";
}


}
?>
```

**ajax.js**

```
// Customise those settings

var seconds = 5;
var divid = "timediv";
var url = "boo.php";

////////////////////////////////
//
// Refreshing the DIV
//
////////////////////////////////

function refreshdiv(){

// The XMLHttpRequest object

var xmlHttp;
try{
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e){
alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
return false;
}
}
}

// Timestamp for preventing IE caching the GET request

fetch_unix_timestamp = function()
{
return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))
}

var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
var nocacheurl = url+"?t="+timestamp;

// The code...

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}
}
xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

// Start the refreshing process

var seconds;
window.onload = function startrefresh(){
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}
```

What the script is suppose to do check every 5 seconds if there is if there is a username in the database called Admin then show a gritter notification if there is.

Any ideas what I can do? thanks.

Comment: You are echoing out JS from an AJAX call... and the JS is wrapped in not one but two document ready functions. Neither of which are needed if the DOM is fully loaded, that by the time an AJAX call is made, you'd hope it would be huh...

Comment: why are people still doing Ajax this way when you have jQuery?!

Comment: Also, check what really gets printed (for example, add output buffering and log the output before sending) - don't forget, php has variables starting with dollar sign and you're echo'ing jquery code that contains dollar function... the real output may differ from what you expect.

Comment: @Songo because its faster and he clearly doesn't have jquery tagged

Comment: @jayharris faster? by how long? 1 micro second? 2 micro seconds? this is a clear case of premature optimization.

Comment: @Songo apparently he does have jquery included lol, yea its overkill.

Comment: @poncha I'm not too experienced with jQuery but even when I change the script to echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('alert');</script>"; it doesn't work but does if i add it manually in the HTML page.

Comment: @JayHarris problem is, the code that his server side outputs is using jquery, so he needs it anyway ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reverse your string notation on the second echo statement that doesn't work.
change double quote to a single qoute like this

```
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        ...more stuff... 
        title: 'title text',
        ...more stufff...
       ";
```

to

```
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
         ...more stuff..
        title: "title text",
        ...more stuff...
        ';
```

why this works is because double quotes will look for variables inside the string and single quotes doesn't. so when you have `$(document)` this inside of the double quote php thinks its a var

**EDIT: since the echo statement is working**

the use of `innerHTML` method doesn't evaluate scripts it only evaluates html tags.
so if you want the response to evaluate the in coming echo statement use the jQuery function `append()`

that being said change

```
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
```

to

```
$('#divid').append(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just tried this but unfortunately the same thing happens.

Comment: @user1626410 if your calling this and expecting it to work from an ajax call, of course it won't work.

Comment: Isn't the Ajax code just running the php code every 5 seconds?

Comment: i added some javascript or jQuery edits to my answer, haven't tested but this should evaluate the response from the php script